# Adjective to describe activities that enhance or require fine motor skills

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for an **adjective** for defining the **activities** that enhance or require fine motor skills (neurosurgery, jewelry-making).

I expected it to be related to the word **craftsmanship**, but according to the sources that I used, the word "crafty", that is the only cognate in the form of an adjective, has a different meaning.

Comment: It's often called [***precision work***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22used+for+precision+work%22). I'm not sure I'd call that "high motor skills" though - it seems to me you need far more sophisticated motor skills to do things like skiing and surfing. But we don't call those activities "precision work" because they don't actually *produce* an artefact made to fine tolerances.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks! Not exactly what I was looking for, but it's better than nothing :)

Comment: All I can say is [Precision work is the essence of neurosurgery,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22precision+work+is+the+essence+of+neurosurgery%22) and [Jewelry-making is such precision work.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22jewelry-making+is+such+precision+work%22)

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe there is a single word that carries the meaning you are looking for. It's a perfect opportunity to mess around and come up with your own word, like

- deftcentric
- dextrordinary
- nimblesome

After all, someone had to be the first one to use every word we know.

Comment: This is a great idea to come up with new words, but in this case, my proficiency of English is not great enough to comprehend these blendings.

Comment: @Eduard Your proficiency is exceeded only by your graciousness. Would there were more of you and fewer down voters. You and I are at least participating.